# Scrollbar inside fixed 100% div without Javascript

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

Ok, so I have a fixed `div` over on the right side of the screen that is the height of the `window`. When content exceeds the space of the `div`, I want the `div` to overflow with a `scrollbar`.

I have managed to do this in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox.

[SSCCE](http://jsfiddle.net/sHx6t/)

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="inner">
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#outer{
    position    : fixed;
    top         : 0;
    right       : 0;
    display     : table;
    z-index     : 200;
    width       : 320px;
    height      : 100%;
}

div#middle {
    display     : table-cell !important;
    max-width   : 300px;
max-height  : 100%;
}

div#inner {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Why doesn't it work? What can I do to fix it?

I realize I could bind event to window re-sizing and force set the `div` height based on that, but I would much prefer a `CSS` solution.

Comment: #inner will be 100% of the height of its container, which is #middle. #middle has no max-height, so will expand indefinitely, producing no scrollbar.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I left of the `max-height` in my code here, but it exists in my SSCCE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the container with the overflow:auto; absolute. http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/49SY8/

```
body, html
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

div#outer{
    position    : fixed;
    top         : 0;
    right       : 0;
    z-index     : 200;
    width       : 320px;
    height      : 100%;
}

div#middle {
    max-width   : 300px;
}

div#inner {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```